# Background color

Tags: objective-c, uibutton, background-color

This is a simple question, but I have looked for the answer without luck.

I want to access the background color of a button to save it into a variable and be able to access it later.

So, I have got an instance property declared in the view controller:

```
@property UIColor *variable;
```

and, in my method:

```
-(IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender {
    variable = sender.backgroundColor;
}
```

but I get the error:

> property backgroundcolor not found in object of type _strong id warning.

Where's the mistake?

Comment: -(IBAction)button pressed:(sender:UIButton) I think background colour property is based on sender UIButton.check with that

Comment: [button.backgroundColor = sender.backgroundColor]; not working either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have three options:

1. Change the `sender` property from `id` to `UIButton *`.

   ```
   - (IBAction)buttonPressed:(UIButton *)sender {
       self.variable = sender.backgroundColor;
   }
   ```
2. Call the `backgroundColor` getter method instead of using the `backgroundColor` property.

   ```
   - (IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender {
       self.variable = [sender backgroundColor];
   }
   ```
3. Use a cast on `sender`.

   ```
   - (IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender {
       self.variable = ((UIButton *)sender).backgroundColor;
   }
   ```

The main issue you have is that you can't use property references on objects of type `id`.